# how does sklearn's Adaboost predict_proba works internally?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost, ensemble-learning

I'm using sklearn's  'predict_proba()' to predict the probability of a sample belonging to a category for each estimators in Adaboost classifier.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
clf = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=50)
for estimator in clf.estimators_:
    print estimator.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Adaboost implements its predict_proba() like this:

> https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb39b49/sklearn/ensemble/weight_boosting.py#L733

DecisionTreeClassifier is sklearn's base estimator for Adaboost classifier.
DecisionTreeClassifier implements its predict_proba() like this:

> https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bb39b49/sklearn/tree/tree.py#L549

Anyone kindly tell me how predict_proba() of Adaboost internally calculates the probability? Is there any references with the same topic which can help me ? Please inform me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the "how it works" section of [Adaboost](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/cv/adaboost_matas.pdf) is of some use?